# How to run Fortune's algorithm to make a Voronoi Diagram inside an irregular polygon?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Say I have a set of points. I spread these points randomly inside an irregular polygon, like [these](https://d138zd1ktt9iqe.cloudfront.net/media/seo_landing_files/irregular-polygons-1631012090.png). Is it possible to create a Voronoi diagram of these points inside of this kind of polygon through Fortune's Algorithm? If so, how?

Comment: Being able to generate a Voronoi diagram doesn't appear to help with designing an algorithm to spread out points randomly inside an irregular polygon, so even if the answer was "yes" it doesn't seem to help you with your problem.

Comment: Fixed the question, meant to ask if I could make a Voronoi Diagram WITH those points, not to spread them.

Comment: Wouldn't this be just running Fortune's algorithm normally, and then clipping to the polygon?

Comment: @RaymondChen: not along the polygon edges. Chek the upper-right figure: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_main.htm

Comment: Oh, you want the polygon's sides to participate in the Voronoi diagram. You didn't say that. All you talked about were points. If you read the description of Fortune's algorithm, it operates only on point sets. So you'd have to adapt it somehow to accept segments. That is a research topic, not suitable for this site. The boost library appears to have done that research, so you can ask the authors. Or just use the boost library. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Short answer: no. A Voronoi diagram has no concept of boundaries. You build it for a point set (as @Raymond Chen said), and some of the polygons extend to infinity.  It would of course be simple to clip the infinite polygons to a boundary, but the result would not be a Vornonoi diagram.

Comment: Ok, so if it won't be a Voronoi diagram, does that mean something like Lloyd's Algorithm couldn't work?

Comment: @RaymondChen: the problem was solved more than 30 years ago.

Comment: Fortune's method works with line segments as well ! https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/10515.10549

Comment: @Yves Daoust Does this mean that Lloyd's Algorithm would work?

Comment: Lloyd's algorithm is not a Voronoi contruction algorithm !?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, but isn't it used to spread a set of points evenly throughout a polygon by moving the points to the center of the cells made until the points no longer move? Like in bitbanging.space/posts/lloyds-algorithm

Comment: @HB: Lloyd's algorithm is not a Voronoi contruction algorithm, your question does not make sense.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I should have been clearer. If I'm understanding correctly, Lloyd's Algorithm uses Fortune's Algorithm to make a Voronoi Diagram of a set of points, moves the points to the centroids of the cells, and then repeats until the points stop changing their positions(or only slightly change). Since the boundaries of the polygon are being used, making some of the cells shaped irregularly, would Lloyd's Algorithm still be able to space the points evenly inside of the polygon? Thank you.

Comment: (The cells are not "irregular", they are just correct.) Yes, Lloyd's principle applies.

Comment: @Yves Daoest Thank you so much for explaining, this really helped.